# How to use generic type in function parameter from generic class in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, swift-protocols

I have a class that generates queries for SQLite using functions that can concatenates one to another to look like a 'native' SQL sentence.

This is the currently working protocol:

```
/// Protocol for any object directly related with a database table.
public protocol Table {

    /// Generic enum implementing the table columns.
    associatedtype Columns: (RawRepresentable & CodingKey & CaseIterable & Hashable)

    /// The name of the table that will be represented in the entity. 
    /// Could be declarated as let in the struct that implements this protocol.
    static var tablename: String { get }
}
```

Here a struct implementing Table protocol

```
public struct TMAEVersion : Table {

    /// Properties
    public var statusMobile: String?
    public var version: String?

    /// Overriding the default name to account for the special name of the table
    public var tablename: String = "TMAEVersion"

    /// Table columns keys
    public enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey, CaseIterable {
        case statusMobile = "status_mobile"
        case version = "Version"
    }

    public typealias Columns = CodingKeys
}
```

Here is the currently working Query class implementing the function using the Table protocol:

```
public class Query<T> {

    // MARK: Properties

    public var columns = [String]()
    public var table: String = ""
    public var literal: String = ""

    fileprivate var showLogs: Bool = true

    // MARK: Init

    public init(literal: String) {
        self.literal = literal
    }

    /// Empty init for normal queries that don't take a literal
    public init(showingLogs: Bool? = nil) {
        if let showingLogs = showingLogs { showLogs = showingLogs }
    }
}

public extension Query where T: Table {

    // MARK: Select

    func generateSelect(_ distinct: Bool? = nil , _ columns: [String], from tablename: String) -> Query {
        let statement = Select(distinct: distinct ?? false, columns: columns)
        self.columns = statement.columns
        self.table = tablename
        self.literal += statement.sentence
        return self
    }

    func select(distinct: Bool? = nil, _ columns: CodingKey...) -> Query {
        return generateSelect(distinct ?? false, columns.map { $0.stringValue }, from: T.tablename)
    }

    func select(distinct: Bool? = nil, _ columns: T.Columns...) -> Query {
        return generateSelect(distinct ?? false, columns.map { $0.stringValue }, from: T.tablename)
    }

    /// Note: Comparator and Operator are enums containing cases like:
    /// - Comparator: equal, diff, greaterThan...
    /// - Operator: and, or...
    func generateWhere(_ col: String, _ comp: Comparator, _ val: Any, _ op: Operator?) -> Query {
        let statement = Where(column: col, value: val, comparator: comp, operator: op)
        self.literal += statement.sentence
        return self
    }

    func `where`(_ lc: CodingKey, _ comp: Comparator, _ rc: CodingKey) -> Query {
        return generateWhere(column, comp, value, nil)
    }
}
```

Working example:

```
public func currentVersion() -> String? {
    return Query<TMAEVersion>()
            .select(.Version)
            .order(by: .Version)
            .execute().first?
            .Version
}
```

I want to avoid the need of doing `Query<SomeTable>()` so what I've try is this (and it's where the error appears):

```
func select<T: Table>(distinct: Bool?, columns: [T.Columns]) -> Query {
    // Code...
}
```

The error shows: "Generic parameter 'T' is not used in function signature".

I know that doing this solve the problem, but I need to avoid the parameter `from: T.Type` and I don't know what should I do.

```
func select<T: Table>(from: T.Type, distinct: Bool?, columns: [T.Columns]) -> Query
```

Besides I tried to pass Table protocol in the init() function but it requires to have a property so... the problem persists.

Any ideas?

**Edited:** Added examples and implementations

Comment: @JoakimDanielson It's currently returning `-> Query` in my code. The working functions are doing just something like `Query<SomeTable>().select(.field1, .filed2).where(.field3, .equal, 1).execute()`

Comment: So you have a function in the class Query that returns a Query instance? Shouldn't it be declared static then? I must say, it's very hard to understand what you want to accomplish with this code.

Comment: It’s totally unclear why Table is a protocol, let alone why it is a generic protocol. Please show concrete examples of what you are trying to do. What is a specific Query and Table? What are you then trying to generalize and why?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson What I've accomplished so far is to generate SQLite queries concatenating functions as I show in the examples. But what I want to accomplish now is to generate them without the <#type#> just passing it in the parameters or somehow in the constructor if it were possible.

Comment: @matt Table is a protocol just because I've created a lot of structs that need to conform having a table name and columns. I've edited the post with some examples.

Comment: Your concrete example is very helpful, but makes your request very surprising. What syntax do you expect to work for `currentVersion()`? Without `Query<TMAEVersion>`, how do you expect it to know which Table to use? Is `currentVersion()` a instance method or a top-level function?

Comment: @RobNapier I know that only putting away `<TMAEVersion>` won't work. The point of this request is to figure out if there's a way to avoid <type> to get out the error: *Generic parameter 'T' is not used in function signature* caused by the **needed** absence of 'T' in this signature `func select<T: Table>(distinct: Bool?, columns: [T.Columns]) -> Query`

Comment: I don't understand how this applies to "I want to avoid the need of doing Query<SomeTable>()". You need to write `SomeTable` *somewhere* (the system has to know what table to use). So what do you want `currentVersion()` to look like if not the current code? (That said, the fact that it returns `self` seems completely wrong. Query should be a struct, and each method should return a new Query that modifies the old Query to add additional information. Just like SwiftUI's new View type.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have this syntax:

```
let sentence = Query<SomeTable>().select(.field1, .field2)
```

and you want this syntax:

```
let sentence = Query().select(.field1, .field2)
```

There are a lot of minor errors in your code, and I think you actually mean you want this syntax (`select` is a *static* method):

```
let sentence = Query.select(.field1, .field2)
```

In order to do that, Columns need to know their Table. As you've written this, it's legal to have two different Tables that have the same Columns type, and then this is ambiguous. (Note that the above syntax is definitely impossible, because there's no way to know what enum `.field1` belongs to, but we can get closer).

So first, we need a ColumnIdentifier that knows its Table:

```
public protocol ColumnIdentifier: RawRepresentable & CodingKey & CaseIterable & Hashable {
    associatedtype TableType: Table
}
```

Next, Table needs to assert that its ColumnIdentifer belongs to it. This will prevent multiple Table types from referencing the same ColumnIdentifier.

```
public protocol Table {
    associatedtype Columns: ColumnIdentifier where Columns.TableType == Self
    static var tablename: String { get }
}
```

Then Query would look like (slightly simplified):

```
struct Query<T: Table> {
    static func select<C: ColumnIdentifier>(_ columns: C...) -> Query
        where C.TableType == T
    {
        return Query()
    }
}
```

And as an example Table implementation:

```
struct SomeTable: Table {
    enum Columns: String, ColumnIdentifier {
        case field1
        case field2
        typealias TableType = SomeTable
    }

    static var tablename: String { "table" }
}
```

Note that I don't believe there's any way to avoid the `typealias TableType = SomeTable`. Nesting one type inside another does not connect them in any way. You can't say "my containing type" or anything like that.

This approach will prevent tables from cross-linking other table's column identifiers. For example:

```
struct OtherTable: Table {
    typealias Columns = SomeTable.Columns
    static var tablename: String { "otherTable" }
}
// 'Table' requires the types 'OtherTable' and 'SomeTable.Columns.TableType' (aka 'SomeTable') be equivalent
```

With all that, you can get (close to) the syntax you're describing:

```
let sentence = Query.select(SomeTable.Columns.field1, .field2)
```

Note that you still need `SomeTable` here *somewhere*. Otherwise you don't know what enum `.field1` comes from.

Personally, I wouldn't do it this way. I'd use the `from` version. It's clear and simple.

```
public protocol Table {
    associatedtype Columns: ColumnIdentifier
    static var tablename: String { get }
}

public protocol ColumnIdentifier: RawRepresentable & CodingKey & CaseIterable & Hashable {}

struct Query<T: Table> {
    static func select(from: T.Type = T.self, columns: T.Columns...) -> Query
    {
        return Query()
    }
}

struct SomeTable: Table {
    enum Columns: String, ColumnIdentifier {
        case field1
        case field2
    }
}

let sentence = Query.select(from: SomeTable.self, columns: .field1, .field2)
```

Note the little trick of `from: T.Type = T.self`. That means "when the return type is known, you don't need to include it." So for example, this will work without the `from`:

```
func f() -> Query<SomeTable> {
    return Query.select(columns: .field1, .field2)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. The problem with this solution is that it is not able to concatenate functions, which is the current functionality of my code. Implementing `static func select(from: T.Type = T.self, columns: T.Columns...) -> Query` is OK for the `select` sentence, but this means that I must do the same for `where` sentences, `inner join` sentences and so on and that's no completely practical.